# updating slider using select list values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a jquery slider using flickerplate and the content of the slider has to be sorted according to the value selected in the select list.
The problem is, whenever i choose an entry in the select list, the slider content changes but looses all the css styles. I think its because of the initialization of flickerplate, but i cant figure out how to fix it, please help.

This is my code:

```
<select id="sort" name="sort" onchange="sortSlider()">
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
    <option value="c">C</option>
    <option value="d">D</option>
</select>

<div class="flicker-example">
    <ul>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            window.onload = sortSlider;
            var storeid = window.localStorage.getItem('storeid');

            function sortSlider() {
                $(".flicker-example ul li").remove();
                var selection = document.getElementById('sort').value;
                /* call the php that has the php array which is json_encoded */
                $.getJSON('http://testdb2.weby.biz/deallist.php', function(data) {
                    /* data will hold the php array as a javascript object */
                    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                        if (val.Store_Id == storeid && val.Product_Type_Name == selection) {
                            $(".flicker-example ul").append('<li data-background="' + val.Product_Variant_Image + '"><div class="flick-title">' + val.Product_Brand_Name + '</div><div class="flick-sub-text">' + val.Product_Variant_Name + '</div></li>');
                        }
                    });

                    $('.flicker-example').flickerplate({
                        auto_flick: true,
                        auto_flick_delay: 8,
                        flick_animation: 'transform-slide'

                    });

                });

            }
        </script>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't nest your `script` tag inside the `ul`.  It's not correct from an HTML standpoint, and it offers zero benefit.  That belongs either at the end of the document or ideally in the `head` section.

Comment: Also, the correct format for your `onload` bind is `window.onload = sortSlider` without the parentheses, as you're assigning a function to an event handler, not calling the function itself.

Comment: edited it, thanx ! any solution for the main problem?